# Is there a dynamic object type for references that comes from different classes?

Tags: java, android, reference

Ok I have two classes the first one is named **Class1** and the second one is **Class2**.
So the thing I want to do is sending a reference of **Class1** into the **Class2**. To do this I need these kind of codes:

**Class1:**

```
public class Class1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public int Var1 = 5;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new Class2(this));
    }
}

public class Class2 extends SurfaceView {
    Class1 Obj1;               //Here!
    public Class2(Class1 Obj){ //And here I don't want to
                               //Use Class1 as a type.
                               //Is there any Global type?
        this.Obj1 = Obj;
    }
    public void EditVar1(){
        Obj.Var1 = 10;
    }
}
```

To take a reference of **Class1**: I should use Object's type as **Class1**. I want to use these codes in more than one projects: So I should edit the **Obj**'s type "Class1" for each project as long as their main class name is different. Is there any global type to use here? Also I tried to use Context as object type with this I can't reach Var1. Anyway I don't know what is it too. If someone can explain what is it I'll be appreciative. Thank you for any responds!

Answer (score 0):

Their nearest ancestor in this case is java.lang.Object, like all Java classes.
For Activity, its parent is context, as you tried using. If you then want to access the specific properties and methods an Activity has, that its parent doesn't have, you have to cast the object. E.g.:

```
Class1 obj1;
public Class2(Activity obj) {
    this.obj1 = (Class1) obj;
}
```

If you keep a reference to the superclass instead of the derived class and you assign the derived object to the superclass object, you lose the specific properties of the derived. This is known as [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: So, This is imposible what I want? :"D